# Rails 3 and jQuery plugin that uses Images

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, image

With Rails, when i want to use an image in a view, i have to use the tag:

```
image_tag("myimage.png", ...etc)
```

in my html.erb.  That fine.  The result is that a ?1234321323423 is put after the name of the image in the src of the  html tag.

if i try to put a regular `<img src="xxx.jpg"></img>`, the picture is not found!!

My problem is i use a jQuery plugin for a carousel that try to load images from the js source.  Since the ?12334234434 is not put at the end of the src, the images dont load.

How can i bypass this issue?

Is there a way to tell Rails to load theses images without the trailing ?12342523343?

Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to use `image_tag`, but you do have to use the correct path.

Chances are very good that your URI looks something like `mysite.com/controller/:id/action`, so by using `xxx.jpg`, your browser will be looking for `mysite.com/controller/:id/xxx.jpg`.

Try using `/images/xxx.jpg`.

Comment: omg... i'm such a noob.  Thanks, my path was just wrong!!! forgot the "/" in front of images.  :-(